# react await async function component inside array

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to dynamically create content using an async functional component. However I am running into problems with being able to render it. Basically I have an async call to look for the amount of different "categories" there are in a project and then create ItemCards for every items inside the categories.

I have a call to the back end server to get the different categories and store them in an array. Then it processes the ItemCards.

I read somewhere that it has probably something to do with promisses; and so I have tried using react hooks (useEffect()) but it still doesnt work with Promise.all. Additionally I tried removing the async and await from the ItemCard function and it seem to work.

Here is the code for getting the different project categories:

```
async GetProjectCategories(){
        await axios.get("http://backend.com/category")
        .then(async (res) => {
            var result = [];
            for (var resdata of res.data) {
                result.push(
                    <div key = {"category:"+resdata._id}>
                        <h3>resdata.catName</h3>
                        <ItemCards data = {resdata}/>
                    </div>
                );
            }
            
            this.setState({Categories: result});
            
            return;
        })
    }
```

Here is the code for generating the different item cards:

```
async function ItemCards(props){
    console.log(props.data);
    var link = "http://backend.com/item/"+props.data.catLink;
    useEffect(()=>{
        await axios.post(link, {})
        .then((res)=>{
            
        })
    },[])
    
    return (<h1>why is it not working</h1>)
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 0):

Why you shouldn't store `resdata` in state array when you fetch it, and based on changing that state render the `ItemCards` separately from async function `GetProjectCategories`.

Comment: You could edit this answer and make it better by adding the code update you are proposing, and a reason why it should be done that way.